# C++ start under linux

Tags: c++, g++

Hi everyone I tried start old program under linux, but it just closed after start without any error, can someone help me?

```
g++ CForwarder.cpp udpsend.cpp -o CForward -lftd2xx
```

Then

```
cat CForward
```

Return many trash information

https://pastebin.com/vCjkhwu3

This command

```
g++ CForwarder.cpp udpsend.cpp -o CForward -lftd2xx -v
```

Return this information
https://pastebin.com/DuDCUxy9

No idea why, please help

Comment: Why do you cat an executable binary? Can you just execute it? (`./CForward` ?)

Comment: `cat exe` Why are you expecting anythng but garbage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat CForward` doesn't execute CForward, but it writes it to the terminal output (stdout). You want to execute CForward use `./CForward` directly